# What does batching update mean in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I was reading an article on the setState method. I found this text," **Updates to the DOM don’t happen immediately when this.setState is called. React batches updates so elements are re-rendered to the DOM efficiently**.". Can anyone explain what does "batch update" mean?

Answer (score 2):

It means react doesn't react to any update. because that would be inefficient. What React does is wait for some threshold to do multiple updates at once. thats why `setState` function is asynchronus.